# How to create a page or file which outputs xml in Umbraco?

Tags: xml, umbraco

I've done some xslt coding and built a macro, and then I created a new master page template for outputting xml-files, but when I go to the contents section I'm not able to create items from these newly created templates. 
How should I go about to deliver a xml-source? I am thinking about some sort of webservice but I don't know how much I want to push the CMS. Maybe it get's some consequences.

Comment: Please clarify: "when I go to the contents section I'm not able to create items from these newly created templates". Why not? I am assuming (but your question is really vague) that you're constructing XML out of some content that's filled into a content node.

Answer (score 0):

Templates, by themselves, cannot be added to the content section. You must create a Document Type and associate your Template to that Document Type. Only then will you be able to create an instance of that Document Type (along with it's template) inside the Content section.

Also, confirm that your newly created node in the Content section has the correct template by checking on the node's Properties tab.